# How to use Sphix's sphinx.ext.coverage's coverage_show_missing_items?

Tags: python, django, documentation, python-sphinx, documentation-generation

Sorry, I am a newbie trying to add Sphinx to auto-generate documentation for a Django project and also ensure sufficient documentation coverage of the project.

I want to configure Sphinx to tell me which Objects are missing documentation by using the `coverage_show_missing_items` flag, specified here:
https://www.sphinx-doc.org/ar/master/usage/extensions/coverage.html#confval-coverage_show_missing_items

Unfortunately, I have not been able to figure out where/how to set this configuration.  My Google-fu didn't come up with any examples on how to configure these settings.

I'm guessing it should go inside `conf.py` somewhere, but haven't come across any examples on how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With almost every Sphinx extension, one may configure options either in `conf.py` or the command line.  For your case, put this somewhere in your `conf.py` where you see [extensions](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/ar/master/usage/extensions/index.html):

```py
extensions = [
    # Other extensions that you might already use
    # ...
    'sphinx.ext.coverage',
]

# ...
# Configuration of sphinx.ext.coverage
coverage_show_missing_items = True
```

Comment: Thanks Steve.  I should have guessed that it is just regular Python code.

Comment: Just curious and maybe you know, but the coverage extension still isn't telling me which classes are not documented in `docs/build/python.txt`

Comment: Is there another setting that I should use to have Sphinx tell me which classes need to be documented or output a coverage percentage?

Comment: I'd be happy to post another question if that's easier for you :)

Comment: in case it's useful, I'm running sphinx with: `sphinx-build -b coverage docs/source/ docs/build/`

Comment: I have no idea. The documentation is sparse. I would run it through a debugger and put breakpoints in the source of https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/_modules/sphinx/ext/coverage.html#CoverageBuilder